# JavaScript valida números pero no deja borrar en input

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Buen día, soy nuevo en JavaScript, tengo la siguiente función que solo deja ingresar números en un input "x", el inconveniente es que también desactiva la tecla borrar, las teclas direccionales, y la tecla shift.

```
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Por favor alguien que pueda ayudarme a activar dichas teclas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías validar el código ASCII de la tecla presionada, para entonces considerar solamente las que necesites que sean presionadas (backspace, punto, coma, etc). Una vez validado el código ASCII presionado por el usuario, puedo recomendarte que agregues una validación para confirmar que el valor del campo es un número válido

Ejemplo

```js
var x = document.getElementById('temp');

x.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {

  var code = e.which || e.keyCode,
  allowedKeys = [8, 9, 13, 27, 35,36,37,38,39,46,110, 190];
  
  if(allowedKeys.indexOf(code) > -1) {
    return;
  }
  
  if((e.shiftKey || (code < 48 || code > 57)) && (code < 96 || code > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="temp" />
```

Comment: Si escribo 2 puntos .. me lo permite.

Answer (score 1):

Esto te servirá, lo que he hecho ha sido comprobar que la tecla pulsada es alguna de las que has dicho y en ese caso hacer un return; para que continúe con su camino.

```
function validate(evt) {
   var theEvent = evt || window.event;
   var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
   var keysOK = {8,16,37,39,46};

   if(keysOK.indexOf(key)!= -1)
      return;

   key = String.fromCharCode( key );
   var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
   if( !regex.test(key) ) 
   {
      theEvent.returnValue = false;
      if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto tu código si lo ejecutas bajo `keydown` o `keyup` no te dejará borrar o usar teclas especiales, incluso no dejara hacer uso del teclado numérico.

si usas `keypress` no habrá necesidad de modificar tu código puesto que `keypress` no detecta esas teclas como código y puedes hacer uso del teclado numérico.

```js
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="temp" onkeypress="validate()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, es que buscas que solo te permita ingresar numeros el input, que tal si pruebas con un input de tipo number, es decir:

```html
<input type="number" >
```

Saludos

Comment: Esto de momento en chrome es donde funciona, en firefox si deja escribir letras en el input number, aunque sí valida que sean numero, al momento de enviar el formulario