# Javascript, función para solo aceptar números pero pasa puntos(.) y apostrofe (')

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas, intento hacer una función evento en javascript para integrarlo con onKeyPress, dicha función debe pasar únicamente números y algunas teclas especiales (backspace, tab, enter), y hace el filtrado de números pero, a su vez, pasa puntos (.) y apostrofes (').

```
 function numeros(e) {
                key = e.keyCode || e.which;
                permitida = [8, 13, 37, 39, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57];

                aceptarTecla = false
                for (var i in permitida) {
                    if (key == permitida[i]) {
                        aceptarTecla = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!aceptarTecla)
                    return false;
            }
```

Comment: Osea, solo aceptar numeros decimales?

Comment: Hola, no, debe aceptar  únicamente números, sin los puntos.

Comment: Algo asi? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50086/javascript-valida-n%C3%BAmeros-pero-no-deja-borrar-en-input?rq=1

Comment: @einer esa respuesta deja pulsar puntos. pero vaya, todo es mirar aqui http://keycode.info/ y decir que ciertas no las tenga en cuenta

Comment: @Einer, miré la página y lo adapté quedándome algo así

Comment: (mis disculpas por el mensaje vacío)




    `        function numeros(evt) {
              var e = evt || window.event;
              var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
              key = String.fromCharCode(key);
              var num = /[0-9]/;
              if( !num.test(key)) {
                e.returnValue = false;
              }
            }`

Comment: Y te funciona como esperas?

Comment: Excluye los puntos, pero también excluye `enter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
function numeros(e){
   var tecla = e.keyCode;

    if (tecla==8 || tecla==9 || tecla==13){
        return true;
    }
        
    var patron =/[0-9]/;
    var tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numpiso" onkeypress="return numeros(event)">
```

Comment: Hola, Camilo. Funcionó perfecto